# How to show year at the top chart and line color change?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to have chart that looks like this:

[image]

The idea is a line chart where the line changes color after specific date (March 14, 2020) from blue to red, has shade on specific years for example, 2020, and 2022.

[image: similar]

Similar to recession shades and a legend that shows what color means in this pre-covid (blue) and post-covid (red).

I created some random data below

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2023, 3, 31)
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

data = {'Date': date_range,
        'Value': [random.uniform(0.75, 2.6) for _ in range(len(date_range))]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```